# What are valid characters for Windows environment variable names and values?

Tags: windows, environment-variables, special-characters, invalid-characters

After some reseach, I found out that [length limits](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for names are 255 and for values 32767 characters.

But which characters are allowed for *names*?
And which characters are allowed for *values*?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

About variable values: you can use most characters as variable values, including white space. If you use the special characters <, >, |, &, or ^, you must precede them with the escape character (^) or quotation marks. If you use quotation marks, they are included as part of the value because everything following the equal sign is taken as the value.

http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true

Check section "Setting environment variables".

About variable names: in my opinion, for best compatibility with every application, you should limit yourself to letters, numbers, underscore (_) and minus (-).

I'm quite sure that all POSIX valid characters for files are ok, but I did not found any evidence of this.

---

Concerning variable names names we need to also accept parenthesis since  `%ProgramFiles(x86)%` is a well-known envar. From my experiments it seems that in addition to letters and digits characters, these characters are valid `_(){}[]$*+-\/"#',;.@!?` and these characters are not valid `%<>^&|=:`.

I didn't do an exhaustive search but just tested most common non alphanumeric characters.

And just for the fun of it you can name an envar `%_(){}[]$*+-\/"#',;.@!?%`:

```
C:\>set _(){}[]$*+-\/"#',;.@!?=xyz

C:\>echo %_(){}[]$*+-\/"#',;.@!?%
xyz
```

Comment: spaces in env names are valid , so are emoji 

Answer (score 7):

It seems like `<>^&|` are also valid characters, as long as they are properly escaped:

```
C:\>set ^<^>^^^&^|=xyz

C:\>echo %<>^&|%
xyz
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the only prohibited character is equal ("=") sign - from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/environment-variables:

> The name of an environment variable cannot include an equal sign (=).