# How can i include a pipe in a variable?

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to put a pipe in a variable. However, i can't seem to.

If i do `set elfheader=|ELF`, i just get:

"'ELF' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

This is beacuse batch executes things literally.

I've tried something like:

```
set elfheader=(
|ELF
)
```

and it doesn't work.

I know why this happens, it's beacuse batch executes things literally and does this (however that is not the question i am asking):

"okay, oh, we want to set a variable. currently (... oh, pipe. so set that to ( and let's go execute the next command. hmm... what is "ELF"? what?"

TL;DR/To clarify, i am trying to put "|ELF" in a variable, in the batch programming language. However, it fails.

EDIT: This is not to clarify what can be used. I want to put that in a variable, not know what can not be used. I want to avoid that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are vaild characters for environment variable names and values?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635695/what-are-vaild-characters-for-environment-variable-names-and-values)

Comment: @NineBerry Not that question, sorry.

Comment: Yes, the answer is there. Use ^ as an escape character

Comment: @NineBerry I know, but the question there is not the question i am asking.  And OP never asked "how do i avoid it?". It is just additional information, however this should be classified as a separate question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing you want to assign the pipe *character* `|` to a variable, there are two options:

1. To use quotation marks around the entire assignment expression:

   ```
   set "elfheader=|ELF"
   ```

   Note that the quotation marks do not become part of the value. Let me recommend this method, because it avoids spacial handling of also other special characters; in addition, this avoids unintended trailing spaces to be appended in case there are some after the second `"`. However, this syntax only works in case the [command extensions](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) are enabled, which is the default anyway.
2. To use escaping by the character `^`:

   ```
   set elfheader=^|ELF
   ```

   This works also with command extensions disabled (which is rarely the case though), but you need to take care for every single special character, like `^`, `&`, `<`, `>`, `|`, and when the command line is placed within a parenthesised block of code, also `(`, `)`, and when [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) is enabled, also `!`.