# gitlab throwing an export error for variable declaration - oddly never throwing it before - god knows how

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have the usual section

```
variables:
  DESTINATION: "dev" 
  dev-SERVERNUMBERS: "0 1"
```

And, this had been working all long and suddenly. Gitlab CI is complaining and giving the following error message

```
/bin/bash: line 103: export: `dev-SERVERNUMBERS=0 1': not a valid identifier
```

Initially, I thought I was exporting something wrong. But, it looks like that is how gitlab runners work they export your variables to make them available to all jobs within your pipeline. I have NO export statement within any before_script.

I can understand why it is complaining because it expects the variable to have double quotes around it in order to export. But, it DID NOT complain now for atleast 2 months, so I cannot understand why now ?

I find gitlab-ci just so unpredictable and extremely frustrating to use. By now, if I had automated this build of mine via shell scripts I would have be on my way. And, I have been stuck on this error for 3 days now. It does not even print out any debug echos that I have set up and straight away gives this line number which has nothing to do with my .gitlab-ci.yaml
At the very least it should give the verbose command that is trying to execute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash is complaining about the environment variable name (the identifier) not necessarily the value. `-` is not an allowed character in environment variable names. You can only use alphanumerics (`a-Z`, `0-9`), and underscores (`_`).

This is a limitation of bash, not GitLab CI.

```sh
export foo="0 1"  # OK
export foo-bar="0 1"  # Not OK
bash: export: `foo-bar=0 1': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: Thank You @sytech that might be it. Oddly, Gitlab-CI did not flag this an error. But, that could have been because Gitlab-CI does run an internal lint on Gitlab-CI yaml scripts and I have only started using this variable 3 days back.
Let me try this first. Thanks again

Comment: Glad that was helpful. GitLab probably doesn't flag this as an error because `-` and other characters may be allowed in other environments ([like Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20635858/5747944)). GitLab doesn't know your runner shell environment ahead of time, so this may help explain that behavior @user1561783